# Django registration serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello every one i need to make three apis for Login , registration and logout...can i make three api with these one serializer...?

serializers.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


    class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
            extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            Token.objects.create(user=user)
            return user
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
# from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
# from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'registration', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('signIn/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view())
]
```

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't do that as *decoupling* enhance the code quality

Comment: can you suggest me how to do...please..i am beginner for django...i want to make login api , registration api, and logout api...